# Failed 14.04 install and BIOS problem

Tags: boot, 14.04, system-installation

After upgrading to 14.04 LTS from 12.04 LTS, I received the error

```
file not found
grub rescue
```

So my boot loader is stuffed and I need to repair it. I decided to use a live USB and repair from there. This is where my trouble really began.

Now I can't access the BIOS on my laptop. I can press escape and can see the options, but each time I choose an option (e.g. F9 - Boot Device Options), it won't proceed any further and returns to the grub error message.

I've followed HP'S instructions on accessing the BIOS with no success.
My laptop is an HP envy 4 Sleekbook.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if live USB you created is working fine or not. If its working fine then go to below.

If you can not select boot device from <kbd>F9</kbd> then use <kbd>Esc</kbd>->`Bios setting` option and change the `Boot order` permanently(You can change it back again to harddisk). Keep Boot from flash drive to first. Then you no need to press <kbd>Esc</kbd>or<kbd>F9</kbd> it will directly boot into flash drive.

Comment: Cheers but that is the problem - I can access the options by pressing esc at boot, but choosing any of the Options F1, F2, F9 etc only takes me back to the error message.

Comment: It seems the issue was the 32GB SSD. I removed the drive, booted the laptop and was able to use the BIOS options.

Comment: Several attempts to repair Grub using Boot Repair failed so I did a clean install of 14.04 which went smoothly. Now, if I can only get the wireless working.....

Comment: you should post it as a new question.